# VBA- Moving a row to another sheet and rearrange the order of that they are in the new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 tabs in my excel workbook: Main Tracking, In Progress, Completed, and Removed. Within the Main Tracking sheet is a list of hundreds of tasks. Columns A through G hold information on each task and column "H" holds a drop down list with the current status of the task. The idea is to be able click on the drop down in Column "H" and adjust the status and if "In Progress" is selected the task in that row will be moved to the "In Progress" tab.

However, the problem I run into is within the "In progress" sheet, I have columns for additional input that were not in the "Main Tracking" sheet. I would also like to retain the "Status" column as the last column to the right in each sheet. In essence I would dropping the data from columns "A:G" into the corresponding "A:G" columns in the "In Progress" tab, but the status column (column "H") would move to the right of my 3 additional columns (so column "K" in this case). Does anyone know a way to do this?

I know this was  a long winded question, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Below is my code to move the data to different cells:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Main Tracking")
        With .Range("H1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
            FilterAndCopy .Cells, "In Progress"
            FilterAndCopy .Cells, "Completed"
            FilterAndCopy .Cells, "Remove"
        End With
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FilterAndCopy(rng As Range, filterStrng As String)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterStrng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            .Copy Destination:=Worksheets(filterStrng).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Delete
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you code it without that complication?  If you can do that and post the code then I'm sure someone will help you out with that last part.

Comment: Added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky working with filtered ranges in-place so easier to move the last column after the paste...

```
Sub FilterAndCopy(rng As Range, filterStrng As String)
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet, rngDest As Range
    Set shtDest = Worksheets(filterStrng)
    Set rngDest = shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filterStrng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            .Copy Destination:=rngDest
            .Delete
            End With
            With shtDest.Range(rngDest, shtDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 7)
                .Cut Destination:=.Offset(0, 3)
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```